# jQuery Validation Plugin Submit Button not working

Tags: jquery, woocommerce

I'm using woo-commerce, and the jQuery validation plugin. because I'm using jQuery to add up fields etc I cant use woocommerce built in validation as it refreshes the page and I lose my values.

http://bookbindingbycrawford.co.uk/products/thesis

But when I hit submit, and fill in the fields that need validation (I've made it just one for testing purposes) the button won't submit.

For the life of me I can't work out why, feel like I'm a bit over my head

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which one u mean as submit button.please mention here.first ur submit event is happening or not.If the event is dont firing means there will be two possibilities.one is ur submit button id may be repeated some where else also. second one is ur click event is not initialized like while registering the event to the button , there is no element in DOM in the name of submit.

Answer (score 0):

**NON-AJAX SOLUTION:** that worked for me, while trying to .submit() with Jquery

Add this code any where in the

```
<input type="hidden"  name="woocommerce_checkout_place_order" value="1" />
```

**AJAX SOLUTION**: Turns out I wasn't including wp_footer(); in my footer file, and thus wasn't getting the BlockUI.js and some additional CSS. Look in to BlockUI.js found in the WooCommerce Assets folder, it has a $.submit() function that explains all the logic.

You can strip out any validation it does here, and make room for your own code!